# How to make an element in a TinyMCE editor treated as a non-editable single item?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

Within our CMS, our users can edit error messages for forms using TinyMCE. The problem is, some of these messages may require dynamic data, e.g. `"Your chosen name 'X' is invalid"`.

To do this, we are using **tokens**. Using the above as an example, our user would type in `"Your chosen name '{name}' is invalid"`, and it would get replaced on render.

I'm currently writing a **plugin for TinyMCE** to better help the user manage these tokens. They would click the icon, select a token from a predefined list, and it would get inserted into the content automatically.

**The problem** I have is how this token is treated within the content editor. At present, it's just text that can be edited, but what I want to do is make TinyMCE treat it as a single element so it can be removed, moved, but the actual token itself can not be edited.

I've tried using the `noneditable` plugin by wrapping the token in a span with the `mceNonEditable` class but this doesn't behave as expected, e.g. you can't backspace delete the token, if the token is at the end of the content you can't type after it, etc.

**So to clarify**, what I essentially want is for TinyMCE to treat some text like it would an image. It would be a solid block, a.k.a. treated as one character/element.

Is this possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After trying about 100 different work arounds, we finally found a solution which works (for our needs anyway).

We're inserting a disabled button with all the styles removed. For example,

```
<input type="button" class="token" value="my token" disabled="disabled" />
```

And then adding some code to onGetContent() to convert the input to plain text.

This solution, although not very elegant,

1. Makes the token behave as a single character/item.
2. Makes it read only.
3. Is dynamic in the context of the editor so we can display our token text.

**Edit**: This is what we ended up with.

[image]

Comment: When I move or copy and paste the button, it loses its class attribute. Have you experienced this/know of a workaround?

Comment: This is a brilliant idea! Wrote a separate plugin that does exactly this, saved me tons of time! NB. Do not forget to append the line `input[type=button|class|value|disabled]` into the `valid_elements` config.

Answer (score 0):

As a duck-tape programmer, I have to ask - can't you use an image? I think TinyMCE used smilies, maybe you can replace those with "elementies" and allow customer to insert them and on save convert to tokens.

Comment: We could, and it's a fallback option we're considering, but then we'd have to create an image for each token as we want the actual token text to be inline in the editor.

Comment: There is also a plugin that according to creators "works more or less". http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2519211&group_id=103281&atid=738747

Comment: Although a nice idea, that plugin isn't robust enough. It simply runs some code on every key press, which if you're quick enough you can get past. See my answer, which is more robust and works for us.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image-tag as token. Using a tinymce UI button to insert this image should work if you replace it after the user has submitted the error message form. For example the image tag you insert could look like this

```
<img  src="../image/token1.gif" class="token1">
```

This way you only need to replace image-tags with the class `token1` after the submit/save.

Answer (score -1):

The real answer to this is just use the `noneditable` plugin.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/noneditable/#noneditable_editable_class

This does what you want.